# Selecting spaces and newlines between otherwise empty brackets (inclusive)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace

Simply put, if a method has no code in it but only whitespace and/or newlines, I would like to remove said whitespace and/or newlines.

Let's give three examples of methods (can apply to if statements or anything else with brackets) that I would not want.

```
void example() {   }

void example() {
}

void example() {

   }
```

This would be the format I would want:

```
void example() {}
```

In order to do so, I could find statements that start with an open curly bracket { and end with a closing curly bracket } that contains newlines and/or spaces in between and replace it with only the opening and closing brackets {}.

So, my question is what the regex would be to select any statements that fit these requirements.

If it helps, I am using IntelliJ Idea, and here is there page for regex: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can use this regular expresion `\{[\s\r\t]+\}` and replace the selected with `{}` i think that this could do the job.

```
code.replaceAll("\\{[\\s\\r\\t]+\\}");
```

i hope that this can help you

Comment: Thanks! I used the top expression with IntelliJ's find and replace since it accepts regex.